# Add style to the imported component is React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-component

I have one independent component 'notification' with its own CSS style. I want to show the notification component in my header component but with different styling. I imported the component in the header, but I unable to add style on it. Please help. I didn't want to change the notification component local style as it broke the notification functionality.

Code for importing notification component.

```
import React from 'react';
import bell from '../../../assets/icons/bell.svg';
import NotificationList from '../notification/NotificationList';

class Search extends React.Component{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
        this.state={
            notificationStatus:false

        }
    }
    render()
    {

        const style={
            position:'absolute',
            top:'70px',
            left:'0px',
            width:'100%',
            height:'auto',
            zindex:'2'
        }
        return(
            <div className="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-11 col-sm-11 search-container">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
                    <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-1 col-sm-1 bell-container flex all-center relative">
                        <img src={bell} alt="bell icon" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <NotificationList style={style} className="notification-component" />
            </div>


        )
    }
}
export default Search;
```

Notification list component

```
import React from 'react';

class NotificationList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state={

        }
    }
    render()
    {
        const title={
            marginBottom:'0px'
        } 
        return(
            <div className="col-md-10 col-md-offsest-1 default-shadow offset-md-1 bg-white pd-10-0 border-radius-10">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12 flex pd-10-0 notification-main-block">
                            <div className="col-md-11">
                                <p className="paragraph" style={title}>Notification title comes here.</p>
                                <p className="small-paragraph" style={title}>2 min ago</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-12 flex pd-10-0 notification-main-block">
                            <div className="col-md-11">
                                <p className="paragraph" style={title}>Notification title comes here.</p>
                                <p className="small-paragraph" style={title}>2 min ago</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-12 flex pd-10-0 notification-main-block">
                            <div className="col-md-11">
                                <p className="paragraph" style={title}>Notification title comes here.</p>
                                <p className="small-paragraph" style={title}>2 min ago</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

        )
    }
}
export default NotificationList;
```

Comment: You should really be using a CSS in JS system with React. Have a look at Emotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have included the style prop in your `notification` component,

```
<NotificationList style={style} className="notification-component" />
```

But you forgot to apply it again in your own export component `Notification list component`

(I tend to forget sometime, it happened to the best of us.)

```
 <div style={this.props.style} className="col-md-10 col-md-offsest-1 default-shadow offset-md-1 bg-white pd-10-0 border-radius-10">
```

I highly recommend [styled-components](https://styled-components.com) for dealing with this styling stuff. Check it out [here](https://styled-components.com)

**Edited:**

After reading again, I see you misunderstand a little bit of the style,
you can apply style on most primitive html component, such as `div, span, section and etc`. But when it comes to component, the style actually will not automatically applied, it is purposely designed that way, and the style will be goes to you `props`. You have to apply it again.

Example:

```
const Parent = ()=>{
 return (
  <div>
   <MyCustomChild style={{fontSize:10}}>Some text</MyCustomChild>
  </div>
 )
}

export const MyCustomChild = (/* Properties */ props)=> 
{
 const {style, children} = props // extract your 'applied' property
 return (
  <div style={style /* passing it here */}> 
   {children}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Did I understand right, that an individual style on an imported Component is not possible then?

Comment: It is possible, and also used commonly, you just have to reapply it. I will update the example for clearer usage.

Answer (score 0):

You have only passed style but not used in `Notification` component.

You can access it using `props` which in your case is `this.props.style`.

Ex.

```
<div style={this.props.style} className="col-md-10 col-md-offsest-1 default-shadow offset-md-1 bg-white pd-10-0 border-radius-10">
```